# How can I import a "class"/object type from my popup.js to my contentScript.js in a chrome extension so that it's accessible by both?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension where the user enters website names into popup.html that are collected/saved in popup.js. I want to remember both the last time the user visited the website and the website name, so I store the websites in chrome.storage.local as objects made by the following constructor:

```
class DelayedSite {
  constructor(domain) {
    this.lastVisit = 0; /* Stores the timestamp since last visit in seconds. */
    this.site = domain; /* The name of the site to delay */
  }
  /*
   * Updates the lastVisit property of the object to hold the 
   * timestamp in seconds since the last time the site was visited. 
   */
  visit() {
    this.lastVisit = Math.ceil((Date.now())/1000);
  }
}
```

Now I want to declare/import this type in contentScript.js so that when I get the objects from local storage they're of that type. How can I do this? Currently, when I get an object from chrome.storage.local, the visit function is undefined, and DelayedSite seems to be undefined (I can't cast to it or create a new object through it) in contentScript.js. Oddly, I can access the object's lastVisit property, despite these other problems. One thing I have tried, which I imagine is a naive approach to the problem (I'm new to JS, forgive me!), is copy and pasting the class so that it's in both files. This does not change anything.

In case it makes it easier to understand, after calling chrome.storage.set to save an array of DelayedSite objects in popup.js, I access them with the following code in contentScript.js:

```
chrome.storage.local.get({"addedSites":[], "restTime":60}, (result) => {
  let addedSites = result.addedSites;
  for (let i = 0; i < addedSites.length; i++) {
    let siteObj = addedSites[i]; 
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

With regards to the object on the 4th line, as described above: I would HOPE that casting this into DelayedSite type would make it work and have a "visit" method, but the cast fails and in the current code the visit method is undefined. However, as mentioned, siteObj.lastVisit works.

Comment: Popup is a totally different page with different "security clearance" so you can't transfer functions between them. Only simple data like strings, numbers, booleans, arrays thereof. You'll have to extract that the class declaration into a separate js file and include it both in the popup and in your content scripts section in manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the response! I've put the class into a file called DelayedObject.js. How do I include it in popup.js now? I tried import "DelayedObject.js"; but it gave an unexpected string syntax error. Sorry for the basic question!

Comment: Just like your other scripts via a `<script src=....></script>` tag.